# Происхождение слова "тренер"

Tags: заимствования, словообразование

Здравствуйте! Правда ли, что слово тренировать произошло от заимствованного слова "тренер" (trainer)", а не наоборот, бессуффиксным способом, как утверждает справочник?

Answer (score 1):

Справочник — в студию!

Кстати, как вы вообще представляете **заимствование** слова "тренировать" с чисто русским суффиксом?

Конечно же, первичное заимствование — тренер.

Comment: Я? Никак не представляю, но увы - не верят... Справочник... Могу потом посмотреть название, если Вам интересно.

P.S. Можно задать такой вопрос: Вы филолог? А то учительнице требуется авторитетное мнение.=)

Comment: > "P.S. Можно задать такой вопрос: Вы филолог? А то учительнице требуется авторитетное мнение.=)"

100500

Comment: ???????????

Comment: Я не филолог. Но у меня масса других достоинств. Я умен и сообразителен.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ли я поняла, что в некоем справочнике утверждается, что слово тренер образовано бессуффиксным способом от слова тренировать? Рискну предположить, что это не справочник, а одно из пособий по подготовке к ЕГЭ не очень грамотного автора, желающего заработать на повышенном спросе на такие издания. Не верьте всему, что написано. Действительно, 
бессуффиксным способом образуются существительные от глаголов (поиск от поискать, бег -  бежать) и прилагательных (синь от синий). Составители "справочника" легкомысленно подошли к подбору примеров, включив такое существительное на основании родственности   с глаголом. Да оно еще и короче глагола! Значит - суффикс убрали. Но это не так. behemothus совершенно прав. Он хоть и не филолог, но даст 100 очков вперед многим «филологам», которые не умеют думать, а верят всему, что напечатано.

Comment: Ларf, ну вы тоже несколько упрощаете. Речь идет о том, что изначально, дескать, было заисмствовано "тренировать" от английского "to train", а потом уже в русском от него образовано "тренер". Эта идея опровергается не заявлением о лекгомысленности её авторов, и даже не интуицией, а вполне конкретными соображениями.

Если интересно, я из изложу подробно, а пока просто отмечу, что в тренировать "-ировать" - типичный глагольный суффикс.

Comment: Да поняла я их. Кстати, я тоже считаю, что суффикс здесь ирова. Почему во всех словарях, которые вчера в сети открыла, суффикс -ир- и -ова-? На каком основании?

Comment: Я не касаюсь вопроса -ирова- - это один суффикс или два. Честно говоря, сомневаюсь я в актаульности этих разговоров. Схоластика. Или чего-то я недопонимаю.